# How to Add Relationships to Neo4j Graph with GraphFrames in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, cypher

I have movies and their respective casts in a Neo4j database, and I want to create `COWORKER` relationships between the casts of each film.

I tried running the cypher query on the database itself and it didn't scale well, so I would like to try and run the query with Spark to see if it is any faster. I am using the `neo4j-spark-connector`, and I think I should use a GraphFrame to store the data. The code goes as follows:

```
import org.neo4j.spark._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.graphframes._

object SparkNeo4jApp extends App {

  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("SparkNeo4j")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.neo4j.bolt.password", "password")

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val neo = Neo4j(sc)
  val graphFrame = neo.pattern(("Person","name"),("WORKED_ON",null), ("Film","title")).partitions(3).rows(1000).loadGraphFrame

  neo.cypher("MATCH (f:Film) WHERE size((f)<-[:WORKED_ON]-())>1 " +
    "WITH[(f)<-[:WORKED_ON]-(p) | p] as coworkers " +
    "UNWIND coworkers as first " +
    "UNWIND coworkers as second WITH first, second WHERE id(first) < id(second) " +
    "MERGE (first)-[r:COWORKER]-(second) " +
    "ON CREATE SET r.strength = 1 " +
    "ON MATCH SET r.strength = r.strength + 1")

  neo.saveGraph(graphFrame)
}
```

If you have any suggestions on how I can get this to work (or on how I could optimize my query), I would really them.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?